# how to search for $exception and $ev special debugger variables on google or yahoo or bing

Tags: debugging, search

I want to find out more about the $ev special variable and special variables in general. Anyone know how to search to ensure [google](http://www.google.co.nz) or [bing](http://www.bing.com) or yahoo doesn't ignore  the $ sign. The usual help about using + in front of the word doesn't seem to help nor speech marks.

Yes I've tried search google for the answer, stack overflow seem to have the same problem :-)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842478/looking-for-special-characters-in-google .

Comment: no quite duplicate - my question is about the variables but hey go ahead and close it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your search more specific by providing context, like `Visual Studio Debugger exception variable`.  Search engines generally don't take punctuation into account for queries, with a few exceptions that have been specifically added as rules. (You can search for "`A+`", but not "`+A`" or "`A+B`".)

Comment: Thanks to Miles above I realise that they are called pseudovariables or pseudoregisters and now I can search for them as I need