# Google Hacking - URLs contain parameters

Tags: regex, search

How do I extract all urls for a certain query that contain parameters:

For example:

```
site:example.com AND inurl:?
```

But since ? is an special char, I don't how to make that to work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your input? What is your expected output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Escape it with a backslash? Are you trying to search google analytics? `?` is a special character with regex, `AND` is not special in a standard regex engine. Where are you using this?

Comment: Just tell me an example, I have tried escaping it, give me an example where it worked please

Comment: Where are you using it??? In a URL make it `%3f`, regex `\?`, elsewhere who knows..

Comment: This question has been asked before and has been closed off-topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842478/looking-for-special-characters-in-google)

Answer (score -1):

The HTML code for `?` is `&#63;`

Your query would then be `site:example.com AND inurl:&#63;`

For example, to constrain a query for `Car`, the URL will be:

https://www.google.ca/search?site=webhp&source=hp&q=Car+site%3Aexample.com+AND+inurl%3A%26%2363%3B&oq=Car+site%3Aexample.com+AND+inurl%3A%26%2363%3B

Comment: It works for me. When I google `Car site:example.com AND inurl:&#63;` I get results for `Car site:example.com AND inurl:?` [Here's the example](https://www.google.ca/search?site=webhp&source=hp&q=Car+site%3Aexample.com+AND+inurl%3A%26%2363%3B&oq=Car+site%3Aexample.com+AND+inurl%3A%26%2363%3B&gs_l=hp.3...1110.8039.0.37757.6.6.0.0.0.0.88.395.6.6.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..0.0.0.0.0VJUhk2SPR8)

Comment: yes, but do you get what you really want? which all websites containing parameters

Comment: OP had trouble embedding `?`. The answer is to use `&#63` instead.

Comment: Third time now: [Car site:example.com AND inurl:?](https://www.google.ca/search?site=webhp&source=hp&q=Car+site%3Aexample.com+AND+inurl%3A%26%2363%3B&oq=Car+site%3Aexample.com+AND+inurl%3A%26%2363%3B)

Comment: thank you but this query just doesn't return anything

Comment: [Screenshot](http://2.1m.yt/saICJDI.png) of google returning the result. Note the `?` coded in the URL as `&#63`.